The Internet Archive suffered a DDOS and their password database may have been compromised
I know many people here rely on the Internet Archive to source books for quotes, but they have been undergoing a DDOS attack and password hashes may have been compromised. If you haven't reused the password used on that system, you'll just want to change it when they're back up, but I know a lot of people use the same password everywhere.

What we know: DDOS attack–fended off for now; defacement of our website via JS library; breach of usernames/email/salted-encrypted passwords.
What we’ve done: Disabled the JS library, scrubbing systems, upgrading security.
Will share more as we know it.

There's a bit more detail on the situation here including the detail that HaveIBeenPwned did receive a database with usernames, email addresses, and bcrypted passwords.

Just noting that the Internet Archive seems to be fully back online, including the ability to archive new URLs in the Wayback Machine. Still recommended to change any places where you used the password.
